# Toastr with AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, toastr

I am trying to get a toastr message to display from JSON retrieved via AJAX. This must be able to change the type of alert and its contents. I am not too clever with JSON, after reading up on it for a while i still have no idea where to start. Any pointers?

Ajax:

```
 function ping(data1)
    {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "bridge/ping.php",
           data: "var1="+data1,
           success: 
        }
     });
```

Toastr:

```
          toastr.success("Message here","Title here)
```

Comment: What data are you sending back from your server?

Comment: I was hoping to send back a number of toastr messages, in the form of type: msg: and title:

Comment: Can you post the actual PHP code?

Comment: I haven't yet written any, I first need to understand how to parse the JSON in to a Toastr notification. Once I can do that, I will know what to send from the server. It will be a simple JSON string

Comment: Why not just `toastr.success(data.message, data.title)`?

Comment: And this will work by sending a JSON string such as, "message": "Hello world","title": "Title here" ?

Comment: Bingo, I just posted a quick demo for ya

Answer (score 6):

Basically on your PHP side, you'll send back an encoded JSON like:

```
$arr = array('message' => 'your message here', 'title' => 'your title here');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Now, on your client, you write the `success`:

```
success: function(data) {
    toastr.success(data.message, data.title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy method of generating multiple toastr notifications, depending on the number of strings in the JSON?

Comment: yes, return an array of messages in the JSON and then loop through them and use toastr

Answer (score 1):

Look at my question: In the JSON array, replace "t" with different toast type ['info'], ['warning'], ['success'],  etc. Then, parse the JSON to fit John Papa's answer.

[Using timeouts with toastr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884810/using-timeouts-with-toastr)

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this. It works perfect.

Server

```
$message = array('message' => 'Success!', 'title' => 'Updated');
return response()->json($message);
```

Client

```
success:function(data){
  setTimeout(() => {
  toastr.success(data.message, data.title);
  },500)
},
```